# Mass dimension of ghost Lagrangian in BRST quantization

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, dimensional-analysis, brst, ghosts

It seems from the BRST transformation rules that the ghost fields should be dimensionless:

For eg. in the Abelian case in 4D:

$$A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} + d_{\mu}c.$$

Then the ghost Lagrangian density $\bar{c}d_{\mu}D^{\mu}c$ is of mass-dimension $2$. That's not a top form. How is it well defined then?

Comment: Hi vvs. Welcome to Phys.SE. Consider to include references to fix conventions.

Comment: The ghost Lagrangian is $S_{gh} = \int b \partial^\mu D_\mu c$. $b$ and $c$ are independent fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $d$ spacetime dimensions, the [mass dimensions](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=mass+dimension) of the gauge field $A_{\mu}$, the [Faddeev-Popov (FP) ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost) $c$, the Faddeev-Popov (FP) antighost $\bar{c}$, and the Lautrup-Nakanishi (LN) auxiliary field $B$, are
$$ [A_{\mu}]~=~\frac{d}{2}-1, \quad [c]~=~\frac{d}{2}-2, \quad \quad [\bar{c}]~=~\frac{d}{2}~=~[B],$$
respectively. The Lagrangian density has mass dimension $[{\cal L}]=d$.

Note that (despite the notation) the $c$ and the $\bar{c}$ are *independent real* Grassmann-odd fields. (The bar on $\bar{c}$ indicates negative ghost number; not complex conjugation.)

Comment: Oh right, thanks! I was stupid enough to assume that [c] = [\bar{c}].